# How to Import a User Defined Function

Tags: c++, import

I'm trying to create a program which can perform numeric integration of any function. In order to do so, the user needs to be able to specify the function (algebraic) that needs to be integrated. Currently, the function is defined as `f[i] = 2 * x[i]`. Is it possible have the user input the function (using `cin` or something)?

```
void fun(int N, float x_min, float x_max, float *f, float *x ) {
    float deltaX = (x_max - x_min) / (N - 1);
    x[0] = x_min;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        f[i] = 2 * x[i];                 // This function should be user defined!
        if (i == N - 1) {       } 
        else {
            x[i+1] = x[i] + deltaX;
        }
    }
}
```

I have included the rest of the program, as the before mentioned might be a bit confusing on its own:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

// Delaring functions
void fun(int N, float x_min, float x_max, float *f, float *x);

int main() {
    int N;                      // Number of nodes
    float x_min, x_max;         // Smallest and greatest value on the x-axis

    cin >> N;                   // Enter the number of nodes

    float *f = new float[N];
    float *x = new float[N];

    cin >> x_min;               // Enter smallest x-value
    cin >> x_max;               // Enter greatest x-value

    fun(N, x_min, x_max, f, x);

    // Dome some more stuff here (approximation / integration)!

    delete[] f;             // Remember to clear the pointer from the memory!
    delete[] x;             // Remember to clear the pointer from the memory!

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look into scripting languages.

Comment: You need an expression evaluator, it's not trivial to write one, but it's not excessively hard either. You should be able to find such a thing by googling.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I already know Python and Matlab, and have created the algorithm. Now I'm trying to do it in C++, as I've always wanted to learn it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks! I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to take user input, say a `std::string`, and turn it into something with a `float operator()(float x)`. This is an "Expression evaluator", which @MichaelWalz suggests in a comment.

A simple example follows:

```
struct Expression 
{
    virtual float operator()(float x) const = 0;
}

struct LiteralExpression : public Expression 
{
    LiteralExpression (float data) : data(data)
    float operator()(float x) const { return data; }
private:
    float data;
}

struct XExpression : public Expression 
{
    float operator()(float x) const { return x; }
}

struct AddExpression : public Expression
{
    AddExpression (std::unique_ptr<Expression> lhs, std::unique_ptr<Expression> rhs) : lhs(std::move(lhs)), rhs(std::move(rhs)) {}
    float operator()(float x) const { return lhs(x) + rhs(x); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Expression> lhs;
    std::unique_ptr<Expression> rhs;
}

struct MulExpression : public Expression
{
    MulExpression (std::unique_ptr<Expression> lhs, std::unique_ptr<Expression> rhs) : lhs(std::move(lhs)), rhs(std::move(rhs)) {}
    float operator()(float x) const { return lhs(x) * rhs(x); }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Expression> lhs;
    std::unique_ptr<Expression> rhs;
}

// more operations

std::unique_ptr<Expression> parse_expression(std::string input)
{
    // Order of construction here is precedence of expressions
    std::size_t mul_pos = input.find('*');
    if (mul_pos != input.npos)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Expression> lhs = parse_expression(input.substr(0, mul_pos - 1));
        std::unique_ptr<Expression> rhs = parse_expression(input.substr(mul_pos + 1));
        return make_unique<MulExpression>(std::move(lhs), std::move(rhs));
    }

    std::size_t add_pos = input.find('*');
    if (add_pos != input.npos)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Expression> lhs = parse_expression(input.substr(0, add_pos - 1));
        std::unique_ptr<Expression> rhs = parse_expression(input.substr(add_pos + 1));
        return make_unique<AddExpression>(std::move(lhs), std::move(rhs));
    }

    // Other expressions

    x_pos = input.find('x');
    if (x_pos != input.npos)
    {
         return make_unique<XExpression>();
    }

    float literal = stof(input);
    return make_unique<LiteralExpression>(literal);
}
```